# Last modified date of a directory in OSX

Tags: macos, shell

How do I get the last modified date of a directory in terminal?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -ld .` from inside your directory? Different versions of `ls` use different date and time formats in output

Comment: drwx------@ 52 userid  staff  1768 Apr 17 11:25

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to get the modification date (mtime) and nothing else

```
stat --printf='%y\n' directory_name
```

or, for the date in seconds since the epoch:

```
stat --printf='%Y\n' directory_name
```

this is more straightforward, efficient and robust than solutions involving `ls`/`cut`/`grep`/`awk`/`find` etc

**Edit**

The above was posted before the OP mentioned that this was for OSX in the comments below.

The OP arrived at a solution using `stat`/`date`, and I approve of the solution so I'm adding it here.

First the `stat`

```
stat -f "%m" /path/test.app
```

to get the directory's mtime, then wrap it in a `date` to get it in the required format

```
date -j -f "%s" "$(stat -f "%m" /path/test.app)" +"%Y/%m/%d %T"
```

Comment: @user754905 what OS? OSX? try `--format=%y`, or look at `man 1 stat`

Comment: If I just do stat, I get this: 234881028 33275326 drwxr-xr-x 3 root staff 0 102 "Apr 17 12:02:42 2012" "Mar 22 15:05:11 2012" "Apr 17 11:25:37 2012" "Mar 22 15:05:11 2012" 4096 0 0 /Users/userid/Library/test/test.app/

Comment: Yup, OSX. I basically want to get this "Mar 22 15:05:11 2012" or "Mar 22 2012"

Comment: I don't have OSX, so have a look at [the man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) and see if you can figure it out. I think it'll be something like `stat -f '%m' -t '%b %m %H:%M:%S %Y' dirname`

Comment: This is what I did: date -j -f "%s" "$(stat -f "%m" /path/test.app)" +"%Y/%m/%d %T"

Comment: @user754905 cool, glad you got it sorted. If the `stat`-only thing can't be made to work, a `date ... "$(stat ...)"` combo is the sensible way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -lcdoq your_directory | awk '{print $5" "$6}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive:

```
ls -Rlt | head -n 2 | cut -d ' ' -f10-12
```

Non-recursive:

```
ls -lt | head -n 2 | cut -d ' ' -f10-12
```