# git status - list last modified date

Tags: git

Using git, is it possible to list an unstaged file's last modified date alongside it's path? using eg.

`git status`

or

`git diff --name-only`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Not directly but you can use a pipe:

> Note: original answer updated based on comments

Linux:

```
git status -s | while read mode file; do echo $mode $file $(stat -c %y $file); done
```

Windows:

```
git status -s | while read mode file; do echo $mode $(date --reference=$file +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $file; done
```

OSX ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10198387/2486953)):

```
git status -s | while read mode file; do echo $mode $(stat -f "%Sm" $file) $file; done|sort
```

Comment: that works - with one caveat - i'm using msysgit on windows where it seems `stat` is unavailable. but i've found i can use `date` instead like this:

`git status -s | while read mode file; do echo $mode $(date --reference=$file +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $file; done`

Comment: on my Mac, `stat -c` doesn't seem to work. I did it like this: `git status -s | while read mode file; do echo $mode $(stat -f "%m" $file) $file; done|sort`. source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10198387/2486953

Comment: Does not work with spaces in path respectively $file. Also not working: "$file".

Comment: On macOS catalina, this list files along with file sizes etc, but there are no dates.

Comment: If one has deleted files, then there will be a lot of "No such file or directory" error. To ignore deleted files, on Linux, use `git status -s | while read mode file; do if [ "$mode" != "D" ]; then echo $mode $file $(stat -c %y $file); fi; done`.

Answer (score 17):

Note: I needed to get the modified files sorted by date, so I modified the echo:

```
git status -s | while read mode file; \
  do echo $mode $(stat -c %y $file) $file; \
done|sort -k1,4
```

One line:

```
 git status -s | while read mode file; do echo $mode $(stat -c %y $file) $file; done|sort -k1,4
```

By echoing first the date (`stat`), and then the file, I was able to sort from oldest to newest modification.

---

[Sam Hasler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541/sam-hasler) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141344/git-status-list-last-modified-date/24505757#comment50914510_24505757):

**To preserve spaces** in mode:

```
IFS=''; git status -s | while read -n2 mode; read -n1; read file; do echo $mode $(stat -c %y "$file") $file; done|sort
```

That is:

```
IFS=''; git status -s | while read -n2 mode; read -n1; read file; \ 
  do echo $mode $(stat -c %y "$file") $file; \ 
done|sort
```

Comment: Preserving spaces in `mode`:
`IFS=''; git status -s | while read -n2 mode; read -n1; read file; do echo $mode $(stat -c %y "$file") $file; done|sort -k1.4`

Comment: @SamHasler good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I prefer your solution to the proposed. However, I think you have an error in your sort command. You should use a comma (sort -k1,4), not a dot (sort -k1.4). Dots specify a character in a field whereas I guess you want to sort the first 4 fields.

Comment: @AlexStylianos Agreed. I have edited the answer accordingly.