# Watching files with Git

Tags: git, shell, scripting

I use a little script that queries Git for which files have been recently changed and then takes action based on those files.

When the tool is invoked I run *git status --porcelain* to get a list of files to act upon.

But this breaks down in the following situation:

```
echo "lorum ipsum" > foo.txt
./tool `git status --porcelain` # tool acts upon foo.txt
git checkout .
./tool `git status --porcelain` # tool doesn't know to act upon foo.txt
```

Is there a way to ask Git to tell you which tracked file was last altered even if it's no longer altered in the eyes of Git?

Perhaps the files that were last updated since last Git query? Or the files updated in the last hour?

Comment: There's a more general solution: https://github.com/facebook/watchman (It's a heavy tool. I have not try it myself.)

Comment: You want your script to operate on every file that changed since the last time it was run? (Also your method of operation isn't safe for files with spaces, etc.) You may want to look into `inotify` and its various tools, bindings, etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner the code sample is just psuedocode to show my intent... Yes, more specifically the last time it was run, I'll update the question to be more clear. Thanks, I will look into inotify

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have to propose is what I mentioned in "[git status - list last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505757/6309)":

```
IFS=''; git status -s | while read -n2 mode; read -n1; read file; \ 
  do echo $mode $(stat -c %y "$file") $file; \ 
done|sort
```

That allows me to add to the index and group modifications (done since the last commit), from the oldest to the newest.
By focusing on `git status` output, that avoids checking all the files that haven't changed yet.
On the second call of the pseudo-code from the question, `foo.txt` wouldn't be concerned.

Comment: This is a useful script but it doesn't solve the problem stated in the original question...I'm now thinking that the original question cannot be solved with Git alone...