# Git check when a file was modified

Tags: git, macos, git-status

I use `git status` to check when a file was modified.
But I want to know the exact date & time of the modification. Is there a command for that?

I know I can use Finder to check the date and time of the `Last Modified`. But a command would be much better.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git status - list last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141344/git-status-list-last-modified-date)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no git command to do this.  You can use `ls` to list the last modified time from the command line (`ls -l file` will show the last modified time) or use stat (`stat file` or `stat -x file` for a more verbose output).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the command exist on Mac, but [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) would be a good solution.