# Git Status Deleted File TimeStamp

Tags: git

In my current branch I accidentally deleted a file that was previously tracked. I would like to know if there is anyway to get the timestamp of deletion. The answer below only works for files that have been modified. For deleted files it throws an error as expected because the file no longer exists.

[git status - list last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141344/git-status-list-last-modified-date)