# Mac unix script: given a list of file paths, find the one with latest modified date?

Tags: macos, bash, bsd

If I have a list of file names (absolute path), how do I determine which one is last modified in command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OS X's stat:

```
tr \\n \\0<files.txt|xargs -0 stat -f'%m %N'|sort -rn|head -n1
```

Use `-c'%Y %n'` with GNU stat.

Different ways to find files sorted by modification date:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -f'%m %N' {} +|sort -rn|cut -d' ' -f2-
  for OS X's stat; use -c'%Y %n' with GNU stat
gfind -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'|sort -rn|cut -d' ' -f2-
  %T@ is absolute modification time and %p is pathname
zsh -o dotglob -c 'printf %s\\n **/*(.om)'
  . is a qualifier for regular files
  om orders files by modification time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f | xargs stat --format '%Y :%y %n' | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f5- | head


find . -type f # find all FILES only in the current directory
xargs stat --format '%Y :%y %n' # perform a stat on the file 
                                # ( xargs helps in 'stringing together commands')
                                # %Y time of last modification since Epoch
                                # %y time of last modification human readable
                                # %n file name
sort -nr                        # -n, sort according to numerical value, -r reverse
cut -d' ' -f5                   # cut output by ' ' (space) and print column five
head                            # show the first 10 lines
```

Comment: %y is a bad format, I'm on Mac.

Comment: aha, sorry, my bad.  Take a look at this link [link to site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197938/last-modified-date-of-a-directory-in-osx)

Comment: and the sort does not actually work, as the result of stat is something starts with "16777220 5339950 drwxr-xr-x 4 ...", and the first number is not the date.